# Welcome message getAdditionalHtml?

Tags: template

I'm completely new to Magento and am trying to work my way through a template that I downloaded.

I've got to the welcome message which I understand is set using the "Welcome text" field in the admin area. What I don't understand is the getAdditionalHtml method call. Where is this information set? I'm guessing it's set as a block in one of the XML files but no matter what I try I can't get anything to output here.

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to add a simple text that does not depend on the page or user and you want to add it after the welcome message you can add this piece of code in your layout file:

Add code in page.xml in Header Block section

```
<action method="setAdditionalHtml"><additional>YOUR TEXT HERE</additional></action>
```